# widget: input the px value from user and use it as inline style in widget function

Tags: php, plugin-development, widgets, css

I am trying to dynamically add margin-bottom property to my widget. For example, I am inputting the value "50px" from my widget and want to use this value to adjust margin-bottom property for the widget. The main purpose is to dynamically add space between my widgets.

This is what I have done so far. Its getting me a white screen of death. I think the problem is at margin-bottom: $variable.

Is it allowed to add inline css in widget function? How do I get the $space valye in the div tag?

```
    function widget( $args, $instance ) {
        $space= "200px";
        echo "<html>";
        echo "<body>";
        echo "<div style=margin-bottom: <?echo $space; ?>>";
        if (!empty($photos)):
             //Loop through each attachment..

             foreach ($photos as $photo_id => $photo) : 

                 $url = wp_get_attachment_url($photo_id);
                 $position = strpos($content, $url);

                 if($position){
                    echo wp_get_attachment_image($photo_id, 'thumbnail') ;
                 }
             endforeach;
         endif; 
         echo "</div>";
         echo "</body>";
         echo "</html>";
```

Comment: If that causes white screen please always enable `WP_DEBUG` and include error messages verbatim into your question.

Comment: You are missing a semi-colon after the third `echo`.

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out. I corrected the third echo statement. I also noticed that I was write div style tag with wrong syntax. I have corrected it. But its still not increasing space between my widgets. Am I writing the style correctly? is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Googled some more and found out that closing php tags and writing html as it is a better practice as compared to writing html inside. Made the following changes to the code shared above:

```
    $space=200px;
    ?>
      <div style="margin-bottom:<?php echo $space; ?>" >
    <?php
      //rest of the code
    ?>
      </div>
    <?php
      //rest of the code
```

Space between widgets added!